# xslt template - Changing Cells Per Row in a Grid

Tags: xslt, grid

I am not at all familiar with xsl, can you please help me.  The following code results in 3-cell rows, forming a grid.

```
<xsl:template match="Entity">
    <xsl:if test="position() mod 3 = 1">
      <div class="row">
        <xsl:for-each select=". | following-sibling::*[position() &lt; 3]">
          <xsl:call-template name="SubCatCell" />
        </xsl:for-each>
      </div>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

I think it's dynamically producing the following:

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="cell"></div>
   <div class="cell"></div>
   <div class="cell"></div>
</div>
```

I need it to be 4 cells per row.  What do I need to change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line

```
<xsl:if test="position() mod 3 = 1">
```

is checking if the current line is a multiple of 3, plus one (modular arithmetic).  You need to change the 3 to a 4, so it works on every 4th element, instead of every 3rd.

This line

```
<xsl:for-each select=". | following-sibling::*[position() &lt; 3]">
```

is looping through all elements whose `following-sibling`'s `position()` is less than (`&lt;`) 3.  If you change the 3 to a 4, you will get all the element whose position is less than 4, which is what you want.